# jQuery Clone() not behaving as it should within asp.net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, clone

I have a search box that needs to be within a form so that it can post to another page for a search functionality to work.
I originally had this working fine in Firefox by using an iFrame, but using the search box would simply refresh the when using Internet Explorer.

I found out that it worked fine if I simply created another form underneath the current one, however this obviously leaves it in the wrong place on the page.

I attempted to use the jQuery clone() method that I have succesfully used elsewhere on the site, but this is refusing to work.

I looked around and found another way of using the clone() method and I have it working fine within jsfiddle, but it will not work on my site.

This is the div that I want to populate:

```
 <div id="CustomerSearch">
 2
 </div>
```

And this is the div that I want to be cloned:

```
 <form name="frmCustomerList" action="../CustomerList/default.asp" method="post">
      <div id="CustomerSearchClone"> 
          1
    Customer Search: <br />
        <input type="text"id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="Searchbox" />
         <input type="submit" value="View" name="txtSearchSubmit" />
    </div>
           </form>
```

This is the script that I am using in an external file:

```
var CustomerSearch = jQuery('#CustomerSearch');
var CustomerSearchClone = jQuery('#CustomerSearchClone');

CustomerSearch.html(CustomerSearchClone.clone(true));
```

I have it working in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/de9kc/92/

Any ideas?

Thanks guys

Comment: Looks really hard for me to figure out what you are tring to do. You should explain what do you expect clearly instead of telling us what is not working.

Comment: My page is an asp.net page, so it is all within a form. In order for the search functionality to work on my searchbox I needed it to be within its own form, so I created one below the current asp.net form. The search box works fine, however I want to move it to where it belongs. Since I can't place it within the asp.net form I want to clone it to the correct div. This is what is not working. It works within jsfiddle but not on my page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a .NET guy but the div you are pasting too is still within a form tag so I'm not certain that this wouldn't cause a hiccup for .NET at submission time (or postback, or whatever).

However, with respect to getting the cloned form elements where you wanted them per the layout you demonstrate in your question;

I modified the pre-result html like so:

```
//html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="CustomerSearch">2 Customer Search:</div>
</form>

<form name="frmCustomerList" action="../CustomerList/default.asp" method="post">
    <div id="CustomerSearchClone">1 Customer Search:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="Searchbox" />
        <input type="submit" value="View" name="txtSearchSubmit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

then i used this jQuery:

```
// the vars you already created
var CustomerSearch = jQuery('#CustomerSearch');
var CustomerSearchClone = jQuery('#CustomerSearchClone');

// using .clone(true, true) for deepWithDataAndEvents - not sure if you want this?
// will the .clone(true, true) retain input's link to original form id? I'm uncertain 
// using .children() because clone's intended destination already has a div container
CustomerSearchClone.children().clone(true, true).appendTo(CustomerSearch);

// hide clone's source after cloning; no sense in having both search boxes visible
CustomerSearchClone.hide();
```

**Note:** Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. (per http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

But you are appending the cloned elements into a different form tag, so maybe a non-issue.

I'm just learning jQuery myself, but I thought I would give the solution a shot ;-$

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/de9kc/190/